# two-dimensional array of cgfloat swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm new to swift and to development at all. I'm trying to create **two-dimensional array of cgfloat** and to set the values of the startAngle and endAngle for each variable in the arry, but I'm getting error MSG once I'm trying to run it

**Cannot subscript a value of type '[CGFloat]' with an index of type '()'**

```
 // Create a path based on the center point, radius, and angles you just defined.
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)


 var myGame = [[CGFloat]]()

 let temp = i - 1
 for var x = temp; x <= temp; x++ {
                var line = ""
                for var y = temp; y <= temp; y++ {
                    myGame[x][y] = [startAngle, endAngle]
                    line += String(myGame[x][y])
                    line += " "
                }
                print(line)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to add an array containing two `CGFloat`s into an array of arrays.  Instead of indexing into the array of arrays, just append the new array to your array of arrays:

```
myGame.append([startAngle, endAngle])
```

Comment: can you please show me how to set the CGFloat in?
I'm trying to find the startAngle and endAngle, so I'm doing this:

myGame[x][y] = [startAngle, endAngle]

Comment: What are you trying to set? I'm unclear on your question.

Comment: MyGame is a two dimensional array of CGFloat.  That means myGame[x][y] holds a CGFloat value. You are trying to assign an array of CGFloat to that?

Comment: Describe what the array myGame is holding in words.

Comment: Btw, your for loops are only going to go once each.

Comment: I am basically trying to create array to save for each variable 2 parmeters, the start and the and.

Comment: Declare the array the way you were and then do `myGame.append([startAngle, endAngle])` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a 2-D array in this way

```
var NumColumns = 20
var NumRows = 50
var array = Array<Array<CGFloat>>()
for column in 0...NumColumns
{
    array.append(Array(count:NumRows, repeatedValue:CGFloat()))
}
```

Hope it helps.. :)